# Python 3: Passing an argument that will accept the default value defined in the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, default

Given a block of code:

```
def myFunc(a = "DefaultA"):
    print(a)

a1 = '?'
myFunc(a1)
```

Is there a type or value that I can set 'a1' to so that 'myFunc' will set 'a' to the default value as opposed to the literal value of 'a1', in this case printing "DefaultA"? Preferably I do not need to change any code regarding the definition of 'myFunc'. The goal is to pass all arguments in the code but allow the end user to select a 'default' option for each argument field.

Comment: Just don't provide `myFunc` with `a`. That will set it to it's default value. Just call `myFunc()`.

Comment: The usual way is to set the default value to `None` and have `if a is None: a = 'DefaultA'` inside the function. There’s nothing like what you’re looking for. You can’t pass argument *and* use the default value.

Comment: if you absolutely have to always provide the argument, then you can set the default value to `None` and in the function, check to see if it's provided or not.

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store all the arguments before calling `myFunc` and if the user chooses to use the "default value" then you put a sentinel value in the dictionary for that argument (-1, None, whatever makes sense that is not used as a value for that argument). Then you process this dictionary and remove any (key,value) pairs with a sentinel value before calling `myFunc`. Now you can call the function as `myFunc(**d)`.